# Merging NSManagedObjectContexts - Get Reference to NSManagedObjects in the merged context?

Tags: object, core-data, reference, merge, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a main context that I create all my NSManagedObject's on if said object doesn't have any required fields. However, if I want to create an NSManagedObject subclass that does have required fields, I copy the main managed object context and create the object (that has required fields) on this new context. Once all the required fields for the object have been populated, I merge the duplicate context back into the main context. My issue is that all the references I had to the objects with required fields are still on their old context even after the merge? Is there an option somewhere to say "after the merge switch all my object references to their newly-created counterpart in the merged context"? The reason is that after I merge the contexts, I want to start setting them as related objects to each other, but I get an error saying I can't do so with objects that are in separate contexts. The error makes sense, I am just confused as to how I may switch my NSManagedObject subclass's reference to the new one in the main (merged) context.

Comment: How do you copy an NSManagedObjectContext? - A small code example of what you are doing would be helpful.

Comment: I just create a new MOC and point it at the main MOC's same store coordinator. NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]; 
    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];

Comment: OK, so you create a separate context (not a *copy*). - Still, a small self-contained code example (*added to your question*) would be helpful: How is the new object created, how is the merging done, where do you set relationships, at what point exactly occurs the error, ... ?

Comment: It's hard to show you code snippets; it's in rubymotion, and the entire point of the project is to abstract away the ugliness of using core data, so there are 2 or 3 layers of abstraction that would be a lot to copy and paste and a lot for you to interpret as a developer that I presume is used to Objective-C. The error occurs when I try to set the relationship of either of the objects to the other object, which is still in the other context, not the new one, that was merged. NSInvalidArgumentException: Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'keyboard' between objects in different contexts

Comment: Each object lives in its own context, and you can't establish a relationship between objects in different contexts (as you already know). I don't know what you mean by "Switching object references". "Merging" means that the changes of the old context are merged into the main context, but that does not give you a "new object". - I am still struggling to understand what answer you expect (if you already know about the basic problem).